# jsTree create Node does not work

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to create a jsTree only in javascript but my code does not work well and I can't find where the problem is (the other topics from google did not bring me further too).

I have in my .php file this div :

```
<div id="jstree2">
  <ul id="root2">
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my .js file, I have simply the following code that is executed when the page is ready:

```
$("#root2").append("<li class='2013'>2013<ul>");
$("#root2").append("<li class='jan'>January<li>");
$("#root2").append("<li class='feb'>february<li>");
$("#root2").append("<li class='mar'>Mars<li>");
$("#root2").append("</ul></li>");

$("#jstree2").jstree();
```

The result given is this tree :

|---- 2013 
|
|---- January
|
|----
|
|---- February
|
|----
|
|---- Mars
|
|----

When i write the html direct from the php file (= wenn I dont write it after the php file is loaded), the tree is correctly displayed. How can I make it a way that the creation of the tree is correctly made (that the year 2013 can be opened and closed)?

Comment: You're appending everything to a single node: `$("#root2")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending every element to the root. This should do it:

```
$(function () {
    var yearNode = $('<li>', {
        class: '2013'
    }).text('2013');

    var year = $('<ul>');

    year.appendTo(yearNode);

    $('<li>', {
        class: 'jan'
    }).text('January').appendTo(year);

    $('<li>', {
        class: 'feb'
    }).text('February').appendTo(year);

    $('<li>', {
        class: 'mar'
    }).text('March').appendTo(year);

    yearNode.appendTo($('#root2'));

    $('#jstree2').jstree();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/02bccmqa/)

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten about closing li tags properly. Your html is generated wrong, thats the cause.

```
$("#root2").append("<li class='2013'>2013<ul>")
.append("<li class='jan'>January</li>")
.append("<li class='feb'>february</li>")
.append("<li class='mar'>Mars</li>")
.append("</ul></li>");

$("#jstree2").jstree();
```

Comment: The forgotten / was the reason why there was node without anything indeed, but now I still have every nodes on the same level, but it brought me further, thanks

Comment: Can you print html code that is crated out of your append operations?

Comment: You are right, the html code generated was wrong, everything was on the same level, the response from MelanviaUK works :) Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No problem:) I'm happy, I could give some help with this:)